# The emulator was installed correctly yet it is not running

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, emulation

```
INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\PROBOOK 4540S\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-VanillaIceCream\google_apis\x86_64\ [5904:16828:20240217,171311.802:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\PROBOO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\032d903e-a618-4338-a26c-310bbdf889e6: The system cannot find the file specified. (2) [5904:16828:20240217,171311.804:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\PROBOO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\1fc87348-5057-464d-abf0-0653f24a7a36: The system cannot find the file specified. (2) [5904:16828:20240217,171311.806:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\PROBOO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\4b6307b4-716e-48d2-9f70-fcceb530a2e6: The system cannot find the file specified. (2) WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): DeviceKeyboardHasAssistKey INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 70cc:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 4200 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | IPv4 server found: INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 95:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 95:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 889c:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 889c:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 18a4:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 18a4:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: b0ab:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: b0ab:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: c8b1:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: c8b1:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 88c6:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 88c6:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 70cc:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0

INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\PROBOOK 4540S\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-VanillaIceCream\google_apis\x86_64\ [5904:16828:20240217,171311.802:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\PROBOO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\032d903e-a618-4338-a26c-310bbdf889e6: The system cannot find the file specified. (2) [5904:16828:20240217,171311.804:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\PROBOO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\1fc87348-5057-464d-abf0-0653f24a7a36: The system cannot find the file specified. (2) [5904:16828:20240217,171311.806:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\PROBOO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\4b6307b4-716e-48d2-9f70-fcceb530a2e6: The system cannot find the file specified. (2) WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): DeviceKeyboardHasAssistKey INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 70cc:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 4200 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | IPv4 server found: INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 95:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 95:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 889c:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 889c:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 18a4:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 18a4:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: b0ab:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: b0ab:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: c8b1:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: c8b1:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 88c6:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 88c6:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 70cc:1f34:b602:0:208f:1f34:b602:0
```

I ran the emulator and the result was the error message above
I then proceeded to uninstall Android studio and its emulators but the problem persisted
I am frustrated